# Variable keeps an old value

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router, vue-composition-api

I have a problem in my Vue app: when I click on a product, the navigationAndChange function is triggered, which gets the ID of that product and takes me to the page with that product. There are elements on this page that contain pictures of this product, and the last one should have a class "active" that allows it to have a border, which means that this last image is shown on the screen. The problem is that when implementing the NavigationAndChange function, the imgBlocks variable stores an array with elements that contain the value of the image of the old product, and I need it to change this value when the transition to the page with another product occurs, so that the last element with the image the new product has taken the class "active" . How to do it? I provide the code below.

```
<script setup>
import { computed, ref, onMounted, nextTick } from "vue";
import { useProductStore } from "../stores/store.js";
import { useRouter, RouterLink } from "vue-router";
import btn from "./btn.vue";
import orderBtn from "./orderBtn.vue";

const router = useRouter();
const productStore = useProductStore();
let product = computed(() => productStore.getProduct);
const extraProducts = computed(() => productStore.getExtraProducts);


// change image

let activeImg = ref('');
activeImg.value = product?.value?.thumbnail;
let imgBlocks = ref([]);

onMounted(() => {
 imgBlocks.value = document.querySelectorAll('.img-good');
 let lastNum = imgBlocks.value.length - 1;
 let lastBlock = imgBlocks.value[lastNum];
 lastBlock.classList.add('active')
})


function changeImg(event, img) {
 activeImg.value = img;
 const imgBlock = event.target.closest('.img-good');

 if (imgBlock.classList.contains('active')) {
   imgBlock.classList.remove('active');
 } else {
   imgBlock.classList.add('active');
 }
 for (let i = 0; i < imgBlocks.value.length; i++) {
   if (imgBlocks.value[i] != imgBlock) {
     imgBlocks.value[i].classList.remove('active')
   }
 }
}


// change product 

function changeProduct(extraProduct) {
 productStore.id = extraProduct.id;
 localStorage.setItem("productStore", JSON.stringify(productStore));
 activeImg.value = extraProduct.thumbnail;
  // location.reload()
  //  console.log(imgBlocks.value);
 let images = document.querySelectorAll('.img-good');
 imgBlocks.value = images;
 console.log(imgBlocks.value);
}

function navigateAndChange(extraProduct) {
 // Execute the router navigation first
 router.push(`/productCard/${extraProduct.id}`);

 // Execute the changeProduct function after a delay
 setTimeout(() => {
  changeProduct(extraProduct);
 }, 100);
}

</script>

<template>
 <div>
  <section class="container products">
  
   <div class="products__info">
    <div class="products__info-img">
      <div class="img-gallery" ref="imgGallery">
        <div class="img-good" v-for="image in product.images" @click="changeImg($event, 
         image)" ref="imgBlocks">
          <img :src="image" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <img :src="activeImg" alt="" class="main-img" />
    </div>
    <div class="products__info-description">
      <h3>{{ product.title }}</h3>
      <p>$ {{ product.price }}</p>
      <h4>Product description</h4>
      <p class="description">{{ product.description }}</p>
      <div class="products-order">
        <div class="order-btns">
          <orderBtn text="-" @click="decrease(product)"></orderBtn>
          <div class="ordered-quantity">
            {{ product.amount > 0 ? product.amount : 0 }}
          </div>
          <orderBtn text="+" @click="increase(product)"></orderBtn>
        </div>
        <RouterLink :to="`/shoppingCart`">
          <btn text="Buy NOW"></btn>
        </RouterLink>
        <div class="icon-like" @click="likeProduct($event, product)" :class="{ active: product.liked == true }"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="products__extra">
    <h2>You may be interested in</h2>
    <div class="products__extra-content">
      <div class="extra__item" v-for="extraProduct in extraProducts" :key="extraProduct.id">
        <div class="extra__item-img">
          <RouterLink :to="`/productCard/${extraProduct.id}`" @click="
            navigateAndChange(extraProduct)"></RouterLink>
          <img :src="extraProduct.thumbnail" alt="" />
          <div class="icons">
            <div class="icon-cart" @click="addOrDeleteProduct(extraProduct)" :class="{ active: extraProduct.amount }">
            </div>
            <div class="icon-like" @click="likeProduct($event, extraProduct)"
              :class="{ active: extraProduct.liked == true }"></div>
          </div>
          <h5>{{ Math.ceil(extraProduct.discountPercentage) }} % OFF</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="extra__item-description">
          <h4>{{ extraProduct.title }}</h4>
          <p>$ {{ extraProduct.price }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
</div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of *not great* code here. Sorry for the long post. I would like to address two main aspects of your code though. Updating the product info, and then updating the `active` class on your images. Fair warning, not all of the below code will actually be "correct" for your actual app, and will probably require a certain amount of refactoring to work 100%. Please think of it more as example code.

### Changing product page

You could use a much better strategy for changing products.  A router push followed by a setTimeout delayed `changeProduct` function call is not good practice. It's very hacky.

Given this is how you push

```
router.push(`/productCard/${extraProduct.id}`);
```

I assume you have a route defined something like this

```js
{ path: '/productCard/:id', component: productComponent, props: true }
```

If you don't have `props: true`, you should add it.  This way the `:id` param will automatically be assigned as a prop in your component.

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html

> When `props` is set to `true`, the `route.params` will be set as the component props.

Now if you define a prop `id` on your component, it will receive the `/:id` param from the route URL

```js
const props = defineProps({
  id: {
    type: String, // URL param is always type String. You can cast to Number later if needed
    default: '1'
  }
})
```

Now [watch](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html) this prop and call all your other functions needed to update the product info in your store and on the page.

```
watch(
  () => props.id,
  newId => {
    setNewProduct(newId) // updates store, product object, images array, etc.
  }
)
```

With this strategy, you don't need to do any kind of `setTimeout` shenanigans. Everything will just update reactively based on the route changing.

### Updating image `active` class

I can tell there's a misunderstanding as to how to use your `imgBlocks` variable.  Looking at the relevant div here:

```html
<div class="img-good" v-for="image in product.images" @click="changeImg($event, 
         image)" ref="imgBlocks">
```

Adding `ref="imgBlocks"` is fine, but you're not using it in your script code correctly.  This is called a [template ref](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html).  On mount, `imgBlocks` in your script code will automatically be assigned the physical DOM element for this div. Which means code like this `imgBlocks.value = document.querySelectorAll('.img-good');` is unnecessary and can be removed (the `document` interface should almost **never** be used with Vue).

Actually, I wouldn't even use something like `imgBlocks` at all for this. Using [class bindings](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/class-and-style.html) we can avoid the hassle of manually adding/removing classes, and instead make it conditional based on the images themselves.

After fetching the `product` information, map the product.images array to be an array of image **objects** where one of the properties is called `isActive` initially set to false, (except the first one if you want it already active by default). So then maybe you end up with an image array that looks like this:

```js
product.images = [
    {
      id: 0,
      src: '/foo.jpg',
      isActive: true
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      src: '/bar.jpg',
      isActive: false
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      src: '/baz.jpg',
      isActive: false
    }
  ]
```

Now update the template code to include the following class binding...

```html
<!-- always include a unique key with v-for -->
<div
  v-for="image in product.images"
  :key="image.id"
  @click="changeImg(image)"
>
  <img :src="image.src" alt="" :class="{ active: image.isActive }">
</div>
```

This will assign the class `active` only if `image.isActive` is true. So when an image is clicked the `changeImg` function should set `isActive = true` for whichever image was just clicked, and false on the other images.

```js
function changeImg(image) {
  product.value.images.forEach(
    i => (i.isActive = i.id === image.id ? true : false)
  )
}
```

Now whichever image is clicked will be active. When changing products, always remap `products.images` to be an array of objects with `isActive` property set how you want on initial rendering.

### codesandbox.io example

If it helps, I made a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-cloud-7dz8nv?file=/src/components/productComponent.vue) that implements all of the above advice in a very simplified manner. Like I said at the beginning, my code examples are more for illustrating a better strategy, while the implementation in your actual app will require refactoring to fit your app's design and structure.